# Laravel 4.1 / Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::favorites()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, undefined, laravel-routing

I just have a quick question. A few weeks ago I build a small app where users were able to like a post just for training. This was stored in a favorites table.

Today I wanted to implement that into an application but it does not work anymore.

I am getting this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::favorites()
```

I dont understand this error because I have simply copied the code from the working project. This is my route.

```
Route::post('favorites', ['as' => 'favorites.store', function()
{
Auth::user()->favorites()->attach(Input::get('post-id'));

return Redirect::back();
}]);
```

Can somebody help? Does this have anything to do with Laravel 4.1??? Would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the user model have an `hasMany('favorites')`?

Comment: Feel free to post that as an answer. It is correct. Thanks a lot I forgot that.

Comment: Its good to add an answer and mark it as the correct answer for other people looking for a solution for the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the user model have an `hasMany('favorites')`? Its required to navigate from a user to his favorites.